# efficent way for a parent to get its child's id after pthread_create?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

Consider the next piece of code -

```
pthread_t* threads;

void createWorkers(WorkerType type)
{
    // Create mapper threads and their Container
    for (int i = 0; i < poolSize; ++i)
    {
        // Add new Thread
        ret = pthread_create(&threads[i], nullptr, function, nullptr);

        // HERE THE MAIN THREAD PRINTS THE JUST CREATED THREAD ID (*)
    }
}

int main()
{
    createWorkers();

    // JOINING THE THREADS

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way for the parent (the main thread) to get its child id? For example right after creating a child in line (*)?

Comment: Presumably, you left out the allocation of memory for the 'threads' array to reduce posted code size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per man page, thread id is the same thing as `pthread_t` returned by `pthread_create`. So you can just print that:

```
printf("%d", threads[i]);
```

Comment: While this may work in practice, `pthread_t` is an opaque type, not necessarily arithmetic, and not necessarily an `int` even if it happens to be arithmetic.

Comment: @pilcrow, `printf` is just an example. printf format specifier lacks the type to print `thread_t`, so this is a best I could do.

Comment: But [`pthread_t` might be a structure](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_equal.html#tag_16_426_08), meaning that `printf` couldn't be used meaningfully and portably.

Comment: @pilcrow, and I am totally aware of that. I would tell you more - printing it is meaningless, unless it has some special meaning to you - for example, it matches LWP id you are observing somewhere else - and in this case it is already non-portable and system-specific. My whole point was to show that opaque value **is** the thread id OP is looking for.